# Can I make two separate Http get requests in same service method using angular4?

Tags: angular

I want to achieve something like this

```
MyComponent.ts

getData() {
    servicemethod.subscribe(data => this.result=data)
    // use this.result for further operations.
}
```

This is my service component.

```
 MyService.service.ts

    serviceMethod(args) {
        let result; // best suitable data structure to store the response may be an array or map
        result1 = _http.get(url1).map((res:response) => res.json);
        result2 = _http.get(url2).map((res:response) => res.json);

        add result1 and result2 in result and return it in such a way that it easily retrievable at calling end.
}
```

I want the result of both request in single subscription.Is it possible?
I am using angular 4.0.0 and the http requests are rest api calls in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `forkJoin`

```
serviceMethod(): Observable<any> {
   result1 = _http.get(url1).map((res:response) => res.json);
        result2 = _http.get(url2).map((res:response) => res.json);

  return Observable.forkJoin([result1 , result2 ])
     .map(responses => {
        // responses[0] => result1
        // responses[1] => result2
     });
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rg1gdu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: @Naveen Yadav, let we know if this solution works because it's a good question what you asked and I'm interested. Thanks.

Comment: your is a great solution, I look the DEMO and it work correctly. Could you explain me this istruction "responses => {
      return [].concat(...responses);
      }". Why  you write "concat(...responses)" and not only concat(responses) ? Thanks.

Comment: flatten the responses into an array with all values using ES6 magic: spread operator:

Comment: I tried this solution but facing some issues at the receiving end. Demo was pretty helpful but I dont want to concat the results.So can I retrieve the result like result[0] and result[1], response from request1 and request2 respectively in my component. Currently I am not able to do so. Can you please suggest?

Comment: check this url   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v3xmue?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: superb!! working now...I just removed the .map from return statement as it was suggested in the second demo and its working now...Thanks!!